# How to put an equation into an input prompt

Tags: input, traditional-form

I would like to know how I could put an equation into an input prompt displaying this equation in traditional form. Better an example:
[image: I can't display an equation into a box message]

My objective is that the input box displays the equation instead of the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
Input["Please input a statistic. For example " TraditionalForm[equation]]
```

[image: displaying an equation]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) also works well.

```
<<MaTeX`

Input["Please input a statistic. For example " MaTeX[Defer@Integrate[x, x]]]
```

[image]